# How to receive a role from a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have been trying to make a simple command that gives a role to someone who speaks in chat, lets say they say a bad word, It would give `message.author` the muted role.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let member = message.guild.members.get(author.id);
  var array = fs.readFileSync('./pings.txt').toString().split("\n");
  if (array.includes(message.content)) {
    member.addRole('556210268418605069')
    message.author.send("You have been muted for using one of the pings.")
    message.author.send("If this had a legit reason to do so please message Collier.")
  } else {
    return;
  }
})
```

In this case I am muting someone if they ping `@everyone` or one of the listed pings.

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you check with this line `if (array.includes(message.content))`, is if the message content is only a mention (Example: `CollierPlays: @everyone` ), not more, then give the message author a role.

I changed your code so the bot gets the first role mention in the message an checks if the rolename is in your Array.

This is the code:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  let member = message.guild.members.get(author.id);
  var array = fs.readFileSync('./pings.txt').toString().split("\n");
  if (array.includes(message.mentions.roles.first().name)) {
    member.addRole('556210268418605069')
    message.author.send("You have been muted for using one of the pings.")
    message.author.send("If this had a legit reason to do so please message Collier.")
  } else {
    return;
  }
})
```

**Attention! The name of roles in your text file have to be the same as the mentioned ones, pay attention on lowercase and uppercase otherwise the code wont work.**